# Unable to execute .jar file from terminal despite having Java installed

Tags: java, jdk, execute-command, jar

I've installed the latest release of JDK with NetBeans on Ubuntu. When I attempt to execute a .jar file from the terminal with `java -jar Minecraft.jar`, this is outputted:

```
The program 'java' cannot be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

What are possible fixes to this issue?

Comment: How did you install java ?

Comment: @Soren I downloaded the Linux x64 version, and executed the .sh file on my desktop. It created a folder called jdk1.8.0_151. I didn't want that folder on my desktop, so I dragged it to my home folder. NetBeans functions fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you install JDK manually you must check the setting of the following variables in your environment:

```
JAVA_HOME=~/jdk1.8.0_151
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And you have to change the values if you move the JDK folder.